# How to solve comparing structs as key map c++

Tags: c++, dictionary, key, stdmap

None topic solved my problem of comparing structs as key map in C++.

Structs code following:

```
struct XYZ{
  int x, y, z;
}

struct XYZComp{
  bool operator()(const XYZ& l, const XYZ& r)
  {
    return ((l.x==r.x)&&(l.y==r.y)&&(l.z==r.z));
  }
}
```

Main looks like

```
int main()
{
  map<XYZ, int, XYZComp> m;
  m.insert(std::make_pair<XYZ,int>({1,2,3}, 1)); //ok

  map<XYZ, int, XYZComp>::iterator it = m.find({1,0,3});
  if(it!=m.end())
  {
    std::cout<<"Key exists in map"; 
  }
  else
  {
    m.insert(std::make_pair<XYZ,int>({1,0,3}, 1));
    //never come here 
    //compiler thinks key already exists in map
  }

return 0;
}
```

I just tried without XYZComparer but it still doesn't work.

```
struct XYZ{
  int x,y,z;
  bool operator==(const XYZ& xyz)
  {
    return (x=xyz.x) && (y=xyz.y) && (z=xyz.z);
  }
  bool operator<(const XYZ& xyz)
  {
    return (x>xyz.x) && (y>xyz.y) && (z>xyz.z);
  }
}
```

How to solve comparing these structs XYZ while i am trying existing item in map.

Edit: Compiler thinks structs are the same when at least one number is correct.

Comment: "but it still doesn't work." not helpful.  I could leave it like that and let you work out why (which is just as helpful) or I could explain why it's not helpful to save you the time and effort of looking it up ... 

Yeah - if it's not working, say what you get, and what you were expecting so that people don't have to try and work it out themselves!

Answer (score 6):

The `std::map` uses `<` to order items.  Thus your `struct XYZComp` needs to supply a user-defined `operator <`.

A very simple solution is to use [std::tie](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tie):

```
#include <tuple>
//..
struct XYZComp
{
    int x,y,z;
    bool operator < (const XYZComp& xyz) const
    {
       return std::tie(x, y, z) < std::tie(xyz.x, xyz.y, xyz.z); 
    }
    //...
};
```

The `std::tie` introduces lexicographical ordering to your struct's elements.

You could do the same thing by cascading down the < comparisons, but then the code becomes longer and is easier to make a mistake:

```
struct XYZComp
{
    int x,y,z;
    bool operator < (const XYZComp& xyz) const
    {
       if ( x < xyz.x )
         return true;
       if ( x == xyz.x &&  y < xyz.y )
         return true;
       if ( x == xyz.x && y == xyz.y )
           return z < xyz.z;
       return false;
   }
    //...
};
```

Comment: I had to make the operator<  'const' (MSVC 2019)

Answer (score 1):

The comparator of `std::set` and `std::map` should function as `<`, not `==`. The binary search tree not only needs to know if objects are equal; it needs to give them an order because the data structure is sorted. Overload the `<` operator for your objects.

The objects are considered equal if `!comp(a, b) && !comp(b, a)`. ([Source](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set))

If you overload `<`, you need not explicitly supply the comparator to the container type because the default is comparator is [`std::less`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/less), which wraps the `<` operator.